# How to respond with "410 Gone" for specific URLs

Tags: haproxy

For SEO reasons I want to return "410 Gone" for some specific URLs which I will match using `path_beg` or `path_sub`.

I've tried the following:

```
frontend foo
    mode http
    bind :80

    # 1) this works but I cannot use 410
    http-request deny deny_status 408 if { path_sub bar }

    # 2) this doesn't work at all no matter the code
    http-response set-status 408 if { path_sub test }
```

I cannot use 410 in the first directive with `http-request` because https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#errorfile:

> <code> is the HTTP status code. Currently, HAProxy is capable of generating codes 200, 400, 403, 405, 408, 425, 429, 500, 502, 503, and 504.

The second directive with the `http-response` doesn't have any effect.

How can I return a 410?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error code will be available in the upcoming 2.2 [errorfile](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4.2-errorfile)

Comment: Also confirming in https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/80#issuecomment-644615458